# impresion en PDF con impresora monocromatica

Tags: php

Estoy generando un reporte con la extencion `TCPDF` para `PHP` el problema que estoy teniendo es que al querer imprimirla en una impresora monocromatica la impresion sale mal, al principio crei que era por que estaba mal calibrada, pero cuando termine de calibrar linea por linea, el archivo seguia saliendo ilegible en ciertas partes, le cambie la fuente y el tamaño de letra, pero no ha conseguido que salga legible, de casualidad alguien ha tenido el mismo problema y pudo solucionarlo?

espero se pueda apreciar que esta ilegible 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es como si tuvieras un valor muy bajo de ppp

Comment: @Xerif intente cambiar la letra, la coloque en cpi en vez de px pero no tuve ningun resultado satisfactorio, tambien le cambie el tipo de letra pero aun asi no quiso funcionar, como puedo aumentar los ppp del archivo pdf?